# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut run on ClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Grid / List view content and want to run the javascript code only at Grid View.
I have added the Main Class for Grid ".grid" but it still effect the List view too.

```
// SHOW HIDE GALLERY BUY BUTTONS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.grid li.text').hover( 
    function(){
        $(this).find('.button').delay(400).fadeIn(200);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.button').clearQueue().fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

---

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="grid">Grid View</button>
        <button class="list">List View</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="list">
        <li class="text">Item 1<button class="button">Button</button></li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v57JF/282/)

After the Page loads

1. In List View Button is shown and should stay showed
2. In Grid View Button should be hidden and at a mouseover the list should be shown.

Comment: Please add your HTML to your question. We won't be abel to help you without it.

Comment: Do your elements have the .grid class all the time? If not you can use the :visible selector.

Comment: Also, what does your error log say?

Comment: Well it is hard to add the html here but can forward you the [URL](http://makerkits.at/Shields) to the Page where it runs.

Comment: How can we replicate your issue???

Comment: Try my updated answer!

Comment: @A.Wolff   Questions updated with Demo http://jsfiddle.net/v57JF/282/

Comment: @user3005380 you need to delegate event and should set specific CSS rule too like here: http://jsfiddle.net/v57JF/283/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes

#### CSS

```
#container .list .button {display:block !important;}
```

This overrides the style settings on button made by jQuery

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.grid li.text', function(){
        $(this).find('.button').delay(400).fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.grid li.text', function(){
        $(this).find('.button').clearQueue().fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

This will animate only the grid view button (delegated with [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/))

[check my jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/v57JF/286/)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup was wrong

Here is the [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/v57JF/285/)

```
 $('.styled_view .article_wrapper').hover(
    function(){
         $('.article_button',this).delay(400).fadeIn(200);
     },
    function(){
        $('.article_button',this).clearQueue().fadeOut(400);
  });
```

Comment: This is same code as OP is using just slightly less performant, if it does matter

Comment: @Aditya I have updated the Question above with a same Error at jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v57JF/282/

Comment: @Aditya Thanks but List View should show everytime ;) So it should not be hidden.

Comment: @Aditya Thank you very much! I can see you changed a little bit more on Code.

Comment: @karadayi  Yes , i have made event delegation to be dynamic, cheers :)